# Constraints with variables

Tags: objective-c, constraints

Is there any way to put this `NSUInteger`:

```
NSUInteger number = 20;
```

in this constraint ?

```
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-25-[btn1]-25-[btn2(==btn1)]-25-[btn3(==btn1)]-25-[btn4(==btn1)]-25-[btn5(==btn1)]-25-|"  options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
```

So I want the places where it says 25, to be 20, but it should be represented by `number`.

Note: I want the final product to end up using the variable width:

```
NSUInteger widthOfScreen = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
NSUInteger width = (widthOfScreen - 55 * 5) / 6;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what the `metrics` parameter is for. You pass a dictionary of named metrics, like this:

```
@{@"number": 20}
```

Then in the visual format you use that named metric instead of the hard coded numeric value

```
@"H:|-number-[btn1]-number-[btn2(==btn1)]-number-[btn3(==btn1)]-number-[btn4(==btn1)]-number-[btn5(==btn1)]-number-|"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option if you still have time, use [Masonry](https://github.com/Masonry/Masonry). It shortens up the development time needed to build and modify constraints. For me, it is the only way to go. Variables can just be passed into the constraint maker block.

```
[self.view mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.top.equalTo(number).with.offset(10);
    make.bottom.equalTo(@20).with.offset(10);
    make.left.equalTo([NSNumber numberWithFloat:20.0f]).with.offset(10).with.priorityHigh();
    make.right.eqalTo(number);
}];
```